# After working like a charm for over sixty days, my Lenovo thinkpad Ubuntu 20.04 won't reboot

Tags: 20.04, lenovo, battery, thinkpad, reboot

Back in late April of this year I bought a Lenovo Thinkpad, a refurbished T430. It came installed with Ubuntu 20.04. It worked without a hitch until today (July 1st). Every night I set the system to 'suspend' mode after sixty minutes of inactivity. I had no problem in using the 'suspend' mode for over sixty nights. Last night I left the Thinkpad on battery power alone, knowing it would go into suspension regardless. This morning I found it shut down, no surprise, not the first time I've left it on battery only to find it shut down. I plugged the laptop to the ac adapter, but when I tried to reboot, only the Thinkpad logo would come in. Then the screen blanked out. I waited for five minutes and decided to shut it down again. This Lenovo Thinkpad normally takes less than a minute to reboot after powering up.  In about 20 seconds I should see the Ubuntu logo and the password box, not a blank screen. I left it alone for over five hours to let the battery recharge completely only to come back and see the same problem. FYI: I shut down the Lenovo every  15 days and have had no issues whatsoever with it rebooting before. I was not notified of any system errors prior to this issue, therefore I have no code to give. This T430 came with a i7 Intel CPU, 16GB RAM and a 512GB SSD. No other OS is installed. I've tried to find issues similar to mine on your website, but the ones I did find dealt with problems upon installing Ubuntu 20.04; like I mentioned before, my T430 came already installed with this OS and until today, I've had no issues with it for over 2 months. I have a strong hunch that this problem can be easily solved by someone proficient in Linux, but I'm no expert in Linux, unlike most of the people who use this website. I'd appreciate any one's help on this matter. Thank you. Buzz signing out.

Comment: You don’t happen to have an Ubuntu installation USB or DVD handy, do you? This would let you boot into a “Live” session and check the SSD for error logs.

Comment: It might also be worth doing a "cold" reboot (disconnecting the AC **and** removing the battery)

Comment: I tried the 'cold' reboot method three times and did see a change on the screen upon start up, the Ubuntu logo showed up after the 'Thinkpad' logo while the hd/ssd indicator light briefly came on, which it didn't do before. But still no dice. I'm going to follow up on Matigo's suggestion, and use a USB drive installed with Ubuntu 20.04 to boot into a "live" session and check the SSD's error logs. But first I have to make one. Thanks for your suggestions, guys. Much appreciated.